# mvc controller class to add new data to the model automatically with user button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a class in asp.NET MVC 5 that will add data to my model automatically when a user clicks a button on the view. Specifically the data is a date stamp in one column of the database and a time stamp in the another column. So for instance the database looks much like this

Day  TimeIn  TimeOut

I have two buttons, ClockIn and ClockOut. the first needs to be able to insert into  the Day and the TimeIn columns while the ClockOut will check for the current day against the database and add the current time the user clocks out. Here is the class that I have so far in the controller

```
// Post: Amember1/ClockInOut/ClockIn
    [HttpPost, ActionName("ClockIn")]
    public ActionResult ClockInConfirm()
    {

        string today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        db.TimeClock.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO TimeClock(Day) VALUES [today]");
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");            
    }
```

Here is the view

```
    @model IEnumerable<AteamR2.Models.Amember1>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Day)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TimeIn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TimeOut)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Day)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeIn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeOut)
        </td>
        <td>
           <div class="ClockIn">
               <input type="submit" value="ClockIn" class="buttonIn" />
           </div>
           <div class="ClockOut">
               <input type="submit" value="ClockOut" class="buttonIn" />
           </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
}
</table>
```

I am not really sure where my problem lies but I believe this should be something that is e

Comment: What is the question here.

Comment: I am trying to create a button that will automatically add the day and time to the database without any other input from the user. My question is how can I do that with the controller? C# can easily be used to get the day and time all I am missing is the code to insert that information into the database model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with the way of your running the sql query.

Best practice is to make use of SqlParameter:

```
string day = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
string test = "insert into timeclock(day, time) values (@p1, @p2)";

List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", day));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", time));

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(test, parameters.ToArray());
```

Better way of doing this is to just let the EF construct the SQL query for you:

```
db.TimeClock.Add(new TimeClock() { Day = day, Time = time });
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So the first part of the answer using SqlParameter did not work for me. Is sqlParameter in a specific using library?

Comment: Yes, it is available in System.Data.SqlClient namespace. Did you try the second part?

Comment: I tried a couple of different ways in the second part that did not work as well. I am wondering if perhaps the way I am using the button is not correct. Perhaps when I click it is not accessing the correct command. I will see about the first part again with the library.

Comment: OK after many trials and tribulations the second part of this answer has worked perfectly! Thank you